# Требуется сложить два целых числа А и В

Tags: c#

Требуется написать программу на с#. Дается входные данные
Во входном файле записано два неотрицательных целых числа, не превышающих 10^100, по одному в каждой строке.
Выходные данные
В единственную строку выходного файла нужно вывести одно целое число — сумму чисел А и В, без лидирующих нулей.

Вот что у меня получилось:)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int A, B, i, S;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите числа A и B: ");
            A = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            B = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            S = 0;
            for (i = A; i <= B; i++)
            {
                S += i;
                Console.WriteLine($"Сумма чисел от {A} до {i} = {S}");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: В задании написано сумму двух чисел, а код что считает? И 10^100 не влезет в Int.

Comment: И я на 97% уверен, что это получилось не у тебя, а у кого-то другого, и ты даже не знаешь,  что делает этот код.

Comment: "Вот что у меня получилось" - ничего не получилось.

Comment: А как это решить? Я просто не шарю я бублик.

Comment: @RiAXxx "числа, не превышающих 10^100" - намек на то, что числа в `int` не поместятся. Складывать их надо "в столбик".

Comment: Ссылка на задачу, кстати https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=103 Именно поэтому я уверен, что код написано другим человеком. Человек, решивший на этом сайте хотя бы одну задачу самостоятельно, не напишет такой код, который в вопросе.

Comment: Сложение чисел столбиком в начальных классах проходят. Так можно числа любой разрядности считать, не только до 10^100. Если забыли как это делать: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpq__RU6uuo

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку задача учебная или конкурсная, дам лишь подсказку.

На C# с числами произвольной длины можно работать при помощи структуры [BigInteger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-5.0). В частности, эта структура умеет распарсить себя из строкового представления, а также поддерживает стандартные арифметические операции наподобие сложения.

Но раз задание учебное, я бы порекомендовал не пользоваться готовым решением (это всё же некоторая разновидность читерства), а реализовать самостоятельно поразрядное сложение, а также парсинг и обратную конвертацию в строку. Например, вы можете воспользоваться очевидным (хотя и малоэффективным) представлением числа в виде списка цифр.

Задание подсказывает, что важно не забыть интересный крайний случай: когда количество разрядов суммы меньше или больше количества разрядов слагаемых.

Comment: Во всех тестирующих системах, в которые я пытался скормить решение на шарпе, BigInteger доступен не был. Только на джаве. Впрочем, может сейчас ситуация поменялась.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тю, это же глупо, зачем блокировать штатную функциональность?

Comment: Это скорее всего просто из-за того, что этот тип в сборке, которая не подключена по умолчанию (System.Runtime.Numerics.dll)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Я думал об этом варианте, но вроде ж в .NET Framework отдельной сборки не было?

Comment: Была — System.Numerics.dll, по вашей же ссылке можно посмотреть, переключив слева версию фреймворка. BigInteger всегда подключался отдельно

Comment: @АндрейNOP: А, ну может быть, я уже и не помню точно.

Comment: @VladD, даже в VS надо было отдельно в references подключать System.Numerics - скорее всего она там просто не подключена.